TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'int' when trying to implement the post_save signal with django-axes
I'm trying to create a signal which sents an email informing about an access attempt, when a user fails to provide correct credentials when logging in. Access attempts are traced by the django-axes package. If the failure_limit is reached, an another signal is used. Comparing both values determines if this signal is used at the moment.
The TypeError occurs in failures = instance.failures_since_start.
from axes.models import AccessAttempt
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.mail import mail_admins
from django.template import loader
from tajnanorka.settings import AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT

@receiver(post_save, sender=AccessAttempt)
def login_attempt_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    def _render_email_message(context):
        template = loader.get_template("foo.html")
        return template.render(context)
   
    failures = instance.failures_since_start
    failure_limit = int(AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT)
    

    context = dict(
        failures_since_start = failures,
    )

    subject = 'bar'
    message = _render_email_message(context)

    if failures < failure_limit:
        mail_admins(
            subject,
            message,
            fail_silently=False,
            html_message = message
        )

AccessAttempt model:
class AccessBase(models.Model):
    user_agent = models.CharField(_("User Agent"), max_length=255, db_index=True)

    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(_("IP Address"), null=True, db_index=True)

    username = models.CharField(_("Username"), max_length=255, null=True, db_index=True)

    http_accept = models.CharField(_("HTTP Accept"), max_length=1025)

    path_info = models.CharField(_("Path"), max_length=255)

    attempt_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Attempt Time"), auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = "axes"
        abstract = True
        ordering = ["-attempt_time"]

class AccessAttempt(AccessBase):
    get_data = models.TextField(_("GET Data"))

    post_data = models.TextField(_("POST Data"))

    failures_since_start = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Failed Logins"))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Attempted Access: {self.attempt_time}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("access attempt")
        verbose_name_plural = _("access attempts")
        unique_together = [["username", "ip_address", "user_agent"]]

Here's the whole traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(
               
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 143, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 188, in _view_wrapper
    result = _process_exception(request, e)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 186, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 80, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 143, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 150, in post
    if form.is_valid():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 197, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 192, in errors
    self.full_clean()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 328, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 349, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django_otp\forms.py", line 272, in clean
    self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 250, in clean
    self.user_cache = authenticate(
                      
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 75, in sensitive_variables_wrapper
    return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 91, in authenticate
    user_login_failed.send(
    ^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\axes\signals.py", line 28, in handle_user_login_failed
    AxesProxyHandler.user_login_failed(*args, **kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\axes\helpers.py", line 614, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\axes\handlers\proxy.py", line 119, in user_login_failed
    return cls.get_implementation().user_login_failed(
           
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\axes\handlers\database.py", line 216, in user_login_failed
    attempt.save()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
    ^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in save_base
    post_save.send(
    ^
  File "C:\Users\desp\anaconda3\envs\tajnanorka-venv\Lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\desp\Documents\Django-projects\projekt-tajnanorka\norkamarzen\signals.py", line 108, in login_attempt_email
    if failures < failure_limit:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: '<' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'int'

I've tried to convert failures into int(), but I don't know what to do else. Is there any way to compare these two values?

Did you use an F('failures_since_start') + 1 in the view?

Can you share the view that triggered the signal?

@willeM_ Van Onsem F('failures_since_start') + 1 also doesn't work, unfortunately. The view that triggers the signal is the default login view from django.contrib.auth.views

I'm not saying you need to use that, it was a question if that is in the view.

what exactly saves the AccessAttempt, is that axes?

@willeM_VanOnsem that comes from here, I was going to answer this after logging in today (approved it from the SG yesterday), seems like you beat me to it ;)

You can not use the instance, or at least not directly, since it uses an F expression [Django-doc] to update the counter.
Use .refresh_from_db(…) [Django-doc] to reread the counter from the database:
@receiver(post_save, sender=AccessAttempt)
def login_attempt_email(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    def _render_email_message(context):
        template = loader.get_template('foo.html')
        return template.render(context)

    instance.refresh_from_db()
    failures = instance.failures_since_start
    failure_limit = int(AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT)

    context = dict(
        failures_since_start=failures,
    )

    subject = 'bar'
    message = _render_email_message(context)

    if failures < failure_limit:
        mail_admins(subject, message, fail_silently=False, html_message=message)

Wow, I'm actually suprised how easy this looks right now and how stupid I was. I used .refresh_from_db() but on an instance of failures_since_start field directly. Thank you very much!

This error arises because instance.failures_since_start does not return an integer, but instead a CombinedExpression.
To fix this, you need to make sure that failures_since_start is evaluated as an integer before comparing it to failure_limit.
Try the following:
failures = int(instance.failures_since_start)
failure_limit = int(AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT)


Thank you, but I've done that before, as I've stated at the end of my question. The only difference when evaluating to an integer is that the TypeError chagnes its description to int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'CombinedExpression'
